# PHP MongoDB update multiple fields with one query

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I've tried running this query:

```
$collection->update(
    array('_id' => 'mongoIDhere'),
    array(
        '$set' => array("parent" => 'data'),
        array("parents" => 'data')
    ),
    array("upsert" => true)
);
```

But it will only update the second "set" parameter (which is array("parents" => 'data') ). When done in two separate queries these work fine, but together it doesn't - what gives?!

Answer (score 1):

```
$collection->update(
    array('_id' => 'mongoIDhere'),
    array(
        '$set' => array("parent" => 'data'),
    ),
    array("upsert" => true)
);
```

Remember MongoDB only accepts array in format of key->value pair i.e. `array("parents" => 'data')` should be `$something => array("parents" => 'data')` OR make changed in your php.ini file so that it will be allow null values as key.

Answer (score 1):

Try with **multiple** option

```
$collection->update(
    array('_id' => 'mongoIDhere'),
    array('$set' => array("parent" => 'data')),
    array("upsert" => true, "multiple" => true)
);
```

**"multiple" option**

All documents matching $criteria will be updated. MongoCollection::update() has exactly the opposite behavior of MongoCollection::remove(): it updates one document by default, not all matching documents. It is recommended that you always specify whether you want to update multiple documents or a single document, as the database may change its default behavior at some point in the future.

[Mongocollection in PHP Doc's](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.update.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
$collection->update(
            array('_id' => 'mongoIDhere'),
            array(
                '$set' => 
                          array(
                                 array("parent" => 'data'),
                                 array("parents" => 'data')
                               )
            ),
            array("upsert" => true) 
         );
```

Hope this will work..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library you should try this:

```
$collection->update(
  ['_id' => 'mongoIDhere],
  ['$set' => ['parent' => 'data', 'parent2' => 'data2']],
  ['upsert' => true]
);
```

I hope that you found a way to fix your issue since you asked the question. However I faced same issue today and couldn't find any answer with search engines so I though that this might help other fellas.